# How to make a .MP3 play in a JFrame

Tags: jframe

Today, I've been trying to find a way to make a sound play via JFrame... With a simple amount of code... NOT 30 pages... I know that if I were to use an applet it would be a lot easier but I really need to use a JFrame, so if anyone could let me know if it is even possible to have a reasonable amount of code to simply play a 3 second mp3 for when I click a JButton, for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.applet.*;

AudioClip ac = getAudioClip(getCodeBase(), soundFile);
ac.play();   //play once
ac.stop();   //stop playing
ac.loop();   //play continuously
```

That should work.

Comment: getCodeBase() of what?